# Subscript out of range when trying to active already opened workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code which is to get a spreadsheet from SAP then do some stuff on it. The problem is when I downloaded the excel file from SAP it will be open automatically and when I set the workbook as active workbook to do my job it show the error: "Subscript out of range". I am 100% sure that the path is correct because if I use Workbook.Open it works. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
Sub GetMRO()

Today_Date = GetTodayDate()
Start_Date = StartDate()
WeekNum = WeekDate()

'Startup SAP

If Not IsObject(sApplication) Then
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set sApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
    Set Connection = sApplication.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
    Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
    WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
    WScript.ConnectObject sApplication, "on"
End If

'Access to FBL3N to get data

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "FBL3N"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").text = "MRO"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").text = ""
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").caretPosition = 3
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-LOW").text = Start_Date
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-HIGH").text = Today_Date
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-HIGH").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-HIGH").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[27,12]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[27,12]").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 16
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = "C:\Users\Tung Hoang\Documents\Tung\Equipment\Planning\" & "Week " & WeekNum
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "MRO week " & WeekNum & ".XLSX"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press


Dim wbMRO As Workbook

Set wbMRO = Workbooks("C:\Users\Tung Hoang\Documents\Tung\Equipment\Planning\" & "Week " & WeekNum & "\" & "MRO week " & WeekNum & ".XLSX")
wbMRO.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `wbMRO` without using the filepath? Perhaps see if just using the name of the workbook solves your problem

Comment: I have tried it but still show the error  "subscript out of range"

Comment: When a workbook is already open Workbooks() takes just the name of the workbook, not the full path. It should be Set wbMRO = Workbooks(""MRO week " & WeekNum & ".XLSX")

Answer (score 0):

Try this: if VB coded in current workbook

---

```
Dim wbMRO As Excel.Workbook
Set wbMRO = ThisWorkbook
wbMRO.Activate
```